# Detours corrupts a .NET application

Tags: .net, 64-bit, native, detours

I created a small C# desktop application which has a single button which does this:

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.ShowDialog();
```

In the project settings under Build I **unchecked** "Prefer 32-bit" so that the process created will be a native-architecture application

I then tried to inject this process with a native 64bit DLL using Detours `DetourCreateProcessWithDlls()`
(I'm using the non-free 64 bit detours)

The process starts fine but when I click the button it just hangs and nothing happens.

This happens even if the DLL inject does nothing what so ever.

From what I was able to debug it probably has to do with the rewrite of the import table which detours does to inject the DLL but I could not find what goes wrong or where the hang is.

Is there a known bug in Detours related to this?
I tried contacting the non-existing Microsoft for support on this but did not get any reply yet.

Comment: Hi shoosh, I'm having the exact same issue, also narrowed it down to `DetoursRestoreAfterWith` - did you manage to solve this or understand why this happens?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in Detours. I got Microsoft to fix it. if you have a commercial licence you should contact them and they will send you an update

Answer (score 1):

Though Microsoft can provide a newer version with a fix for this known bug (like you stated in the comments), we also managed to fix it manually by uncommenting the following code section in modules.cpp and commenting out the __debugbreak call:

```
#if 0
    if (pder->pclr != NULL && pder->clr.Flags != ((PDETOUR_CLR_HEADER)pder->pclr)->Flags) {
        // If we had to promote the 32/64-bit agnostic IL to 64-bit, we don't want
        // to restore its IAT.
        __debugbreak();
        return TRUE;
    }
#endif
```

This section actually causes the `DetourRestoreAfterWith` function to refrain from trying to restore the IAT in case of AnyCPU compiled processes. Newer Detours versions simply implement specific logic to handle such cases.